# Multiple websites on same server

Tags: debian, .htaccess, httpd.conf, php.ini

When running multiple websites on same server:

```
root/website1
root/website2
root/website3
```

What should be done to make these websites run intependently - I mean to completely restrict access of PHP (or any other scripting language) to the root folder and each other's folders?

I am thinking of Apache Virtual Host, but will it restrict file access between each vhost as required?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/root/website1/"
    ServerName Website1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/root/website2/"
    ServerName Website2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/root/website3/"
    ServerName Website3
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "run independently"?

Comment: To not have access to each other on the file system.

Answer (score 1):

You can create one PHP-FPM pool per website, each one running under a different user and group.

See there:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-websites-securely-with-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-14-04